# Python (3 if it makes a difference) dictionaries and specific list result order with generator

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, generator

I'd like to consume a list of dictionaries of quad-paired values.  The issue is that `dictionary.values()` can return the values in whatever order the keys happen to be in. This can affect pairing for effective generator/iterator consumption of the list.

Considering the following:

```
import itertools
formfielddata=[
    {'value': '10.16.0.4', 'param': 'target_ips'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.6', 'param': 'target_ips_6'},
    {'param': 'target_ips_7', 'value': '10.16.0.7'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.8', 'param': 'target_ips_8'},
    {'param': 'target_ips_9', 'value': '10.16.0.9'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.10', 'param': 'target_ips_10'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.11', 'param': 'target_ips_11'},
]

apiargs={}
print("%s" % ([dict(zip(*[iter(f.values())]*2)) for f in formfielddata]))
[apiargs.update(dict(zip(*[iter(f.values())]*2))) for f in formfielddata]
print("%s" % (apiargs))
```

which yields:

```
[   {'target_ips': '10.16.0.4'},
    {'target_ips_6': '10.16.0.6'},
    {'10.16.0.7': 'target_ips_7'},
    {'target_ips_8': '10.16.0.8'},
    {'10.16.0.9': 'target_ips_9'},
    {'target_ips_10': '10.16.0.10'},
    {'target_ips_11': '10.16.0.11'}]
{   '10.16.0.7': 'target_ips_7',
    '10.16.0.9': 'target_ips_9',
    'target_ips': '10.16.0.4',
    'target_ips_10': '10.16.0.10',
    'target_ips_11': '10.16.0.11',
    'target_ips_6': '10.16.0.6',
    'target_ips_8': '10.16.0.8'}
```

As you can see, mixing up the value ordering messes up the resulting dictionary.  Is there a way I can put an ordered list of keys into the dictionary or generator in order to get back the values based on the specific order?

EDIT:

I wound up going with the dictionary comprehension for this specific case, however the specific ordering answer proved very useful for doing something else so I wanted to give special mention to it as well.

In the case where the dictionary contents contain a fixed list of keys that I can depend on to always be present (such as the multipart form I was processing) R Nar's answer below makes the most sense (it doesn't require traversing the list index).

What I found, however, is that in the case of a different application where I wanted a dynamic list of attribute/value pairs to be used as an index to Redis, the set sorting turned out to be pretty handy.  I have about 188 possible request arguments to an API which I don't want pounded for repeated requests.  As such I wanted to create a master list of argument ordering so that identical request parameters could be used as part of a Redis cache key.  Here is how that worked:

```
def build_redis_key(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
    '''
    builds the key fingerprint
    '''
    intersect = sorted(set(kwargs.keys()), key = api_param_key_order.index)
    return endpoint.join(['|%s=%s' % (key,kwargs[key]) for key in intersect])
```

Comment: You want to retrieve the values of two dictionaries by identical keys given in the same but arbitrary order?

Comment: well there are [OrderedDicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) but you have identical keys for each dict so you could easily do a dict comp like `{d['value']:d['param'] for d in forfielddata}`

Comment: ^hmmmm that does look like a solution.  I'll test it as soon as I get a chance!  ty

Comment: As a side note, the `%` operator has begun deprecation in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `f.values` with `(v for k,v in sorted(f.items(), key=lambda x:preferred_order.index(x[0])))` should do it:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint
formfielddata = [
    {'value': '10.16.0.4', 'param': 'target_ips'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.6', 'param': 'target_ips_6'},
    {'param': 'target_ips_7', 'value': '10.16.0.7'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.8', 'param': 'target_ips_8'},
    {'param': 'target_ips_9', 'value': '10.16.0.9'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.10', 'param': 'target_ips_10'},
    {'value': '10.16.0.11', 'param': 'target_ips_11'},
]

preferred_order = ['param', 'value']
apiargs = {}

pprint("%s" % ([dict(zip(*[iter(
    (v for k, v in sorted(f.items(), key=lambda x:preferred_order.index(x[0])))
)]*2)) for f in formfielddata]))
[apiargs.update(dict(zip(*[iter(
    (v for k, v in sorted(f.items(), key=lambda x:preferred_order.index(x[0])))
)]*2))) for f in formfielddata]
pprint("%s" % (apiargs))
```

Comment: Note: to solve your broad problem, use a dict comprehension like R Nar suggested.